# What is the name of these elliptic surfaces $E(n)$?

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am referring to the elliptic surfaces $E(n)$, with fibration over $\mathrm{C}\mathbb{P}^1$. They are common in 4-manifold theory and complex geometry. See for example Chapter 7 in Akbulut`s "4-manifolds". Sometimes I read that they are called rational elliptic surfaces. Is this the whole name or is there a more specific name?

Comment: A rational elliptic surfaces is a rational surface that admits an elliptic fibration, only.

Comment: I'm not used to these "too topological" aproachs but it seems to me that you may consider the term "Lefschetz Fibration". 

Take a look at the references of this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106212v1.pdf

I hope they may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elliptic surface $E(1)$ is a rational elliptic surface. It is a blowup of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ at nine points, and the projection to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is constructed by using a pencil of cubics through the nine points of $\mathbb{CP}^2$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4204313/39599) for example.

For $n > 0$, the elliptic surface $E(n)$ is defined to be the fiber sum of $n$ copies of $E(1)$. They all have singular fibers, and are therefore Kähler. Moreover, they have $b^+(E(n)) = 2n - 1$. As $b^+(X) = 2h^{2,0}(X) + 1$ for Kähler surfaces, we see that $h^{2,0}(E(n)) = n - 1$. So for $n > 1$, the canonical bundle $K_{E(n)}$ admits sections and therefore $\kappa(E(n)) \neq -\infty$; in particular, these elliptic surfaces are not rational.

For $n = 2$, the corresponding elliptic surface is an elliptic $K3$ surface.

Beyond that, I am not aware of any particular name for these elliptic surfaces. For more information about them, see the book *$4$-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus* by Gompf and Stipsicz. They are first introduced in chapter $3$.